# Graphing in spherical coordinates

Tags: graphing-functions, spherical-coordinates

So I'm trying to graph an equation that's in spherical coordinates:

$$\rho^2-5\rho = -6$$

Comment: If $\rho$ is the the coordinate in the radial direction and since the equation only allows two values for $\rho$, namely $2$ and $3$, then the set of solutions consists of two spheres with center at the origin and radii $2$ and $3$, respectively.

Comment: Thank you so much! I understand now!